# Can not get android application to build, could not find a resource

Tags: android, android-layout

Whenever I try to build an application with Gradle, I get many errors which I don't know how to solve, I've tried changing the buildtools/compilesdk version along with the appcompat, but it still doesn't work.

```
values.xml:1377: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar'.
values.xml:1380: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorAccent'.
values.xml:1378: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimary'.
values.xml:1379: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimaryDark'.
values.xml:1407: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar'.
values.xml:1410: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorAccent'.
values.xml:1408: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimary'.
values.xml:1409: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimaryDark'.
```

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v13.jar')
    compile files('substrate-api.jar')
    provided files('XposedBridgeApi-54.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'

}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard true
            proguardFile ('proguard-project.txt')
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }
}
```

[values.xml](https://pastebin.com/TJpxsA79)

I am on gradle 1.12 and cannot change to any version above 2.0 (According to the project instructions.

[Github link](https://github.com/M66B/XPrivacy)

Comment: please paste your color.xml and style.xml

Comment: please post your AndroidManifest

Comment: I am not completely sure about it, but the Material Design was introduced with support libs 21+, right? -> https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/rev-archive.html#rev21-0-0 So you can't use attributes like `colorPrimary`, ... You're stick to the Holo-World. :)

Comment: Regarding your values.xml it's coming from the file `<!-- From: file
:/T:/Libraries/Programming/Workspaces/LooseProjects/XPrivacy/res/values/styles.xml -->`, so this should be worth investigating.

Comment: @MohammadAli I have updated the question with the github link, all the needed files should be in there.